# Best Practice for preloading libraries, categories and common methods

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a lot of view controllers that inherit from a core view controller where I've put a few common methods.  It occurred to me that I could also load things like core data, uikit and other heavy libraries in order to load them just once?  Is this best practice or is there any reason not to do this?  Thanks in advance for guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lazy loading is the way to go. Avoid an init storm, which might cause your users to wait for a while on startup. It might be better to have them wait for (hopefully unnoticeable) short amount of times throughout the use of your app. 
In the end it boils down to the best user experience for your app, but in general, lazy loading is the starting point, optimize UI-experience from there.

Comment: how would lazy loading work for #import <CoreData/CoreData.h>?  Just wait until it is needed or is there a way to do if (not loaded), then load?

Comment: #import <CoreData/CoreData.h> does not load the framework at runtime. It is needed to be able to compile your code into a binary. In general, it is good practice to import frameworks in .h files, forward-declare your classes in .h files, and actually import your classes in .m files. This is important for larger projects where it might speed up compilation. There is no difference at runtime for what you do, as the compiled binary is the same. At runtime, the thing that costs time is actually loading data from a disk or network for instance.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks for clarifying this!